# Android - multiple screen support

Tags: android, screen

Suppose I put the image in drawable-xhdpi only and i try to access it in the device having mdpi density. then it's running properly.

But I created one xml in layout-large only. I try to run it in the device having the normal screen then i am getting the **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException**. is it mandatory to create an xml file in the layout folder. can anyone an idea why it is behaving like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the doc [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

> Caution: If all your resources use a size qualifier that is larger
>   than the current screen, the system will not use them and your
>   application will crash at runtime (for example, if all layout
>   resources are tagged with the xlarge qualifier, but the device is a
>   normal-size screen).

I think that answers your query

Comment: Suppose here we have small qualifier then in this case also is it crashed? or is it taking from the small qualifier?

Comment: I haven't tried it , but according to doc it should not crash. You can try checking it

Comment: Yes it is taking from the nearest small qualifier. For example xml file is there only in small qualifier and large qualifier and your device is xlarge then it took the xml file from the large qualifier instead of small qualifier. and thanks for your fast reply.